# Create certificates for self-hosted apps, for access within the LAN

Tags: reverse-proxy, certificate, cloudflare, synology, tunnel

I use Cloudfare Tunnel to access my apps form outside the network, but if I'm at home, I want to skip the tunnel, and access them directly using the same domain name and https connection as if from the internet. I already have pihole as a DNS for this.

I can use a reverse proxy, but the problem is when generating the certificates is a bit time consuming:

1. on Synology NAS where I host may apps I need to disable may firewall
2. on the router I need to open up ports 80 and 443
3. on Cloudfare I need to temporary rename the hostname to something else
4. then I can regenerate the cerfificate (using Let's Encrypt), and undo the changes I did in steps 1-3.

All this only for one domain and every 3 months...

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [DNS challenge.](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/)

Then there's no need to change anything.

Comment: The issue with this is that Synology doesn't let me configure the DNS challenge. Maybe I can use some other tool, or a script to generate and renew the certs.

Comment: Then do the DNS challenge from a different host that can run a sufficiently clever client and manage the certs. If you don't want to do the HTTP challenge, you're not going to like the TLS-ALPN challenge, which leaves the DNS challenge.